# -bash: find_git_branch: command not found

Tags: git, bash, macos, terminal

This should be very simple. I recently noticed that when I type anything into Terminal on Mac it shows this:

```
-bash: find_git_branch: command not found
bogon:git monty$ ls
1.txt       index.html
-bash: find_git_branch: command not found
bogon:git monty$ touch 2.txt
-bash: find_git_branch: command not found
bogon:git monty$ ls
1.txt       2.txt       index.html
-bash: find_git_branch: command not found
```

When before it didn't. Can someone explain why and how to resolve.

Comment: what is the output of `echo $PROMPT_COMMAND`

Comment: $ PROMPT_COMMAND
-bash: find_git_branch: command not found

Comment: Nothing at all . just 
  $ PROMPT_COMMAND

Comment: You probably have something configured in your .bashrc or /etc/bashrc that runs that find_git_branch command every time you type something.  Do a grep find_git_branch in your home directory, and in /etc to try and find where.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the git maintainers only support MaxOS10.9 (mavericks). If you have an earlier version, you can't use their distribution.

Recommended by somebody else at work - use (home)brew. Basically with brew installed you can merely use:

```
brew install git
```

and it will give you an up to date version. Subsequently to get a new version use:

> brew upgrade git

Now brew itself uses git, so it might be that this install is recursive - I had to install it recently for another purpose and it took me several hours - but once you have it there, things should be OK. All I can say is that when I installed brew originally, "git" still referred to the 1.8.x Apple version, and with this change I'm now getting git v2.1.0.

Comment: 1. bogon:~ monty$ git --version 
2. git version 2.10.1 
3. -bash: find_git_branch: command not found
4. bogon:~ monty$ brew upgrade git
5. Error: git not installed
6. -bash: find_git_branch: command not found